# How do I disregard consecutive buy or sell signals

Tags: pine-script

I am using an indicator that gives signals that are for an upper breakout and a lower breakout. The problem is that I would like to disregard an upper or lower breakout alert if the signal has not changed from the previous signal. If there is a change from upper to lower then I want to be alerted. Not if there is an upper signal followed by another upper signal some time later.

I was planning to plot the most recent signal on a chart as equal to 1 if it was an upper signal or to 0 if it was a lower signal. Then I could look for a change to this plot to determine the change in state.

I am a Newbie so please excuse my average code. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
UpBreak =  ta.crossover(src,upper-slope_ph*length)
LBreak = ta.crossunder(src,lower+slope_pl*length)
if (UpBreak)
Direction = 1
if (LBreak)
Direction = 0
plot(Direction)
```

I get an error message Undeclared Identifier "Direction". How do I declare this variable and is there an easier way to achieve the result that I am after?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `Direction` in the local scope and trying to access it in the global scope.

Declare it outside of the if blocks and you are good.

```
UpBreak =  ta.crossover(src,upper-slope_ph*length)
LBreak = ta.crossunder(src,lower+slope_pl*length)

var Direction = 0

if (UpBreak)
    Direction := 1
if (LBreak)
    Direction := 0
plot(Direction)
```

Please note that, you should use the `:=` operator to re-assign values.

Comment: Thanks! the code is working without errors but the plot is not behaving like I want. I need the value of direction to stay at value = 1 until after some time where a candle appears with an LBreak signal. At this point Direction value = 0.

Comment: Then make it a `var` variable. Updated the code.